# Using wget to "checkout" svn repository

Tags: bash, svn, wget

I have a very poorly laid out svn repository that I don't have permission to re-structure.  There are several subprojects spread across the repo at various depths from the repository root.  I want to be able to check out all of the trunks (but not any branch or tag folders) regardless of what depth they are at.  I figure this would be a good problem for wget to solve.  My initial use of wget looked something like this:

```
wget -r -X 'tags' -I "base/of/repo" "http://www.urlrepo.com/"
```

A few issues I ran into while running this command:

1. Wget still grabbed the tags folder even though I thought the -X flag should exclude them
2. The downloaded files are placed into folder "base/of/repo", which isn't terrible, but it would be nice to not save to this path

Thoughts?

Comment: What? You use the svn command line client. Why would you use `wget`? `svn co svn://repo/trunk/`

Comment: Because there are several tags/ and branch/ folders spread throughout the repo, and I don't want to check them out.  I don't believe there is a way to exclude those folders via the svn command line client.

Comment: Don't give up pushing for reorg of the repo.  It's pretty simple and risk free to do from the svn end, and the value is going to be easy to demonstrate.  If you're getting no traction on getting a sensical structure to your source code, polish the resume.  Decent projects are laid out well from top to bottom - lack of attention to such a glaring time suck on this level is likely reflected throughout the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it recursively with `bash` and `svn` using sparse checkout.

Something like:

```
svn co --depth immediates svn://repo/trunk
```

Then on each subfolder, if it is 'tags':

```
svn up --set-depth empty tags
```

Else:

```
svn up --set-depth infinity dirName
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it *might work*, it relies on something that's not 100% guaranteed: That you can use a browser when you use httpd as your Subversion repository server.

You can limit the checkout by using the `--depth` parameter on `svn co` and the `--set-depth` parameter when doing `svn update`. This will allow you to checkout only those folders and directories you want without pulling everything down. This is sometimes referred to as *sparse checkouts*. As a bonus, this is an actual checkout. You can do commits -- something `wget` won't let you do:

```
$ # I want to just checkout the immediate files under the URL:
$ svn co --set-depth=immediates $REPO/trunk/foo
A foo/first
A foo/second
A foo/third
# I want to checkout everything in first and third, but nothing in second:
$ cd foo
$ svn up --set-depth=none second #Removes directory second
$ svn up --set-depth=infinity first third
```

Using this should work with your original example:

```
$ svn co --depth=none http://www.urlrepo.com/ workdir
$ cd workdir
$ svn up --set-depth=none base
$ cd base
$ svn up --set-depth=none of
$ cd of
$ svn up --set-depth=infinity repo
```